# Code equivalent of XAML snippet

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to know the code equivalent of the part that is inside the `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock>
     Hello
     <Run Background="Red">S</Run>
     <Run Background="Blue">O</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

The reason is that I have a converter that returns the `TextBox` content, but I'm not sure what type to return from the converter. I tried some collection types, that contain the string and the 2 `Run` instances but that wouldnt work.

Also I noticed that the following wouldnt work:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text> <--- Added this
        Hello
        <Run Background="Red">S</Run>
        <Run Background="Blue">O</Run>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

So my second question is to which property do I have to bind my converter result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you can add Run blocks via the **InLines** property, e.g.

```
TextBlock txtBlock = new TextBlock();

txtBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "S", Background = Brushes.Red });
txtBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "O", Background = Brushes.Blue });
```

Secondly, you cannot add via "TextBlock.Text" as this is expecting a string, not a collection of Runs.

Comment: thanks! so i will need a multibinding for my converter, where i pass in the textblock and the text. then i use your code in the converter to add the runs to the textblock.Inlines

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <Label>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
            <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="S"/>
            <TextBlock Background="Blue" Text="O"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Label>
```

Add your converter to the binding of each textblocks.I think its more flexible than using the Run

Comment: thanks biju. I already considered this, but it is not applicable to me as I would need to many textblocks

Comment: Then you should try an itemscontrol